# Disable SSL from Wufoo Form

Tags: css, ssl, wufoo

I've uploaded a stylesheet to Dropbox for my Wufoo form (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uee80873gpo1ns/example.css?dl=0), but it's not loading the styles and I think it's because my site (www.franhaines.co.uk) doesn't have an SSL certificate.

I want to now just disable SSL from my form completely but it's proving very hard to find out how to do this, if it is possible at all. Does anyone know how I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not loading styles because link you provided leads to dropbox site, not file itself. Use your hosting where you have your site or anywhere where you can link files directly.

Comment: Great spot! I've amended it so it leads to the actual file now by adding `dl=0` to it. But it unfortunately still doesn't load. :(